# Python commands in command line not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

Why this map do not work at command line?

Just fails silently:

```
python -c "x=range(1000);map(lambda l: print(l), x)"
```

The `map` should traverse the `range` as it works inside Python REPL.

Comment: try calling `python3 -c ...` - `python` is normally Python 2

Comment: Side-note: Using `map` for its side-effects is considered bad form; it's doubly bad because you rely on `lambda` functions unnecessarily (`map(print, x)` would be identical and not involve pointless slowdown/verbosity from `lambda` wrapping). A better solution is either: `print(*x, sep="\n")` which prints all at once (fine for smallish output sequences, but not for millions of outputs) or just using an explicit loop `for l in x: print(l)` (though the latter may not work well for one-liners). If you must `map`, just `list`-ify to force `map` to run: `list(map(print, x))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to run with python2.x (to make sure try running `python --version`)

In python 2 `lambda l: print(l)` is not valid, since print is not a regular function/method.

Try running

```
python3 -c "x=range(1000);map (lambda l:print(l), x)΅
```

If you want a solution that is compatible with both versions, try:

```
python -c "x=range(1000); print('\n'.join(map(lambda l: str(l), x)))"
```

Bonus:
A solution using list comprehensions:

```
python -c "x=range(1000); print('\n'.join([ str(l) for l in x ]))"
```

Comment: `map(print, x)` and `map(str, x)` are a little more terse, no need for `lambda`s.

Answer (score 1):

When you run this code (in python 3), the code is functioning correctly.  However, that the code returns is a map object, which contains the instructions to print the numbers, as is shown here

```
>>> x=range(1000);map (lambda l:print(l), x)
<map object at 0x6ffffd0cba8>
```

To get the numbers to print, you would need to iterate over the map, like

```
>>> x=range(1000)
>>> y=map (lambda l:print(l), x)
>>> for n in y:
...   pass
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
etc.
```